# Find a basis for all polynomials of max grade 2 such that $p(1+x) = p(1-x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the answer is $(1, x^2 - 2x)$, but I do not know how to get there.

Comment: Do you believe that there are no other bases?

Comment: Do you mean maximum degree 2?  Simply let $ax^2+bx+c$ be an arbitrary degree at most 2 polynomial.  Now plug in $1+x$ and $1-x$.  Now set them equal.  Now do algebra and equate coefficients.  You should have a linear system in $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 4):

If $q(x)=p(1+x)$ then $q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ which is an even function (i.e. $q(x)=q(-x))$. This implies $q(x)=a+bx^{2}$ and this gives $p(x)=q(x-1)=a+b(x-1)^{2}=b(x^{2}-2x)+(a+b)$.

Comment: @amdb Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Take $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$. Then given condition implies $$(a_0+a_1+a_2)+(a_1+2a_2)x+a_2x^2=(a_0+a_1+a_2)-(a_1+2a_2)x+a_2x^2$$ so $a_1=-2a_2$. Hence $p(x)=a_0-2a_2x+a_2x^2=a_0+a_2(-2x+x^2)$. So..?

Answer (score 0):

Let $L:P_2 \to P_2$ be defined by $(Lp)(x) = p(1+x) -p(1-x)$.
We want to find a basis for $\ker L$ (note that $\dim P_2=3$).

Note that $L(x \mapsto 1) = 0$, $L(x \mapsto x(x-2)) = 0$ and $L(x \mapsto x) = (x \mapsto -2x)$, hence
$\ker L = \operatorname{sp} \{x \mapsto1 ,x \mapsto x(x-2) \} $.